# How do I do a jointplot in R the same way as I do it python (seaborn package)

Tags: python, r, visualization, seaborn

How do I do a jointplot in R the same way as I do it python (seaborn package)

In python

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.jointplot(bigdiamonds["price"], bigdiamonds["carat"])

<seaborn.axisgrid.JointGrid at 0x207230b0>
```

[image]

How do I do this in R?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Just saw this [in a blog post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/06/wanted-a-perfect-scatterplot-with-marginals/) a couple of weeks ago, it uses the `ggExtra` package and the `ggMarginal` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Marius

I did this from the blog post

```
devtools::install_github("WinVector/WVPlots")
library(WVPlots)
ScatterHist(diamonds, "price", "carat")
```

and got this

[image]

Comment: super naive disclaimer: what's `devtools`? doesn't lemme install it!